# Python - Return a value from a tuple

Tags: python, oop, methods, instance, generator

I'm using `pyacoustid` and I do not understand why this code works (artist is actually the artist and so on..):

```
first = True
        for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                print
            print '%s - %s' % (artist, title)
            print 'http://musicbrainz.org/recording/%s' % rid
            print 'Score: %i%%' % (int(score * 100))
```

while this chunk doesn't (when I print it seems that it is empty):

```
def getFingerprintArtist(self):
        """
        Returns tuples with possible artists fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
        """
        return  [artist for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults]
```

Here is the whole class (suggestions are welcome!):

```
class SongFP:
    """
    Song with FINGERPRINTS
    """
    fpresults = None

    def __init__(self, path = None):
        """
        :param path: the path of the song
        """
        self.path = path
        try:
            self.fpresults = acoustid.match(api_key, path)
        except acoustid.NoBackendError:
            logger(paths['log'], "ERROR: chromaprint library/tool not found")
        except acoustid.FingerprintGenerationError:
            logger(paths['log'], "ERROR: fingerprint could not be calculated")
        except acoustid.WebServiceError, exc:
            logger(paths['log'], ("ERROR: web service request failed: %s" % exc.message))

    def setPath(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def printResults(self):
        first = True
        for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults:
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                print
            print '%s - %s' % (artist, title)
            print 'http://musicbrainz.org/recording/%s' % rid
            print 'Score: %i%%' % (int(score * 100))

    def setFPResults(self):
        self.fpresults = acoustid.match(api_key, self.path)

    def getFingerprintArtist(self):
        """
        Returns tuples with possible artists fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
        """
        return [artist for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults]

    def getFingerprintTitle(self):
        """
        Returns tuples with possible titles fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
        """
        return [title for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults]

    def getFingerPrintID(self):
        """
        Returns tuples with IDs fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
        """
        return [rid for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults]

    def getFingerPrintScore(self):
        """
        Returns tuples with scores fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
        """
        return [score for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults]
```

**NOTE:** `acoustid.match(api_key, path)` returns tuples!

EDIT:

This little example

```
songfp = SongFP(sys.argv[1])
songfp.printResults()
```

where `SongFP` is

```
class SongFP:
    """
    Song with FINGERPRINTS
    """
    fpresults = None

def __init__(self, path = None):
    """
    :param path: the path of the song
    """
    self.path = path
    try:
        self.fpresults = acoustid.match(api_key, path)
    except acoustid.NoBackendError:
        logger(paths['log'], "ERROR: chromaprint library/tool not found")
    except acoustid.FingerprintGenerationError:
        logger(paths['log'], "ERROR: fingerprint could not be calculated")
    except acoustid.WebServiceError, exc:
        logger(paths['log'], ("ERROR: web service request failed: %s" % exc.message))

def getFingerprintArtist(self):
        """
        Returns tuples with possible artists fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
        """
        return [artist for _, _, _, artist in self.fpresults]

def getFingerprintTitle(self):
    """
    Returns tuples with possible titles fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
    """
    return [title for _, _, title, _ in self.fpresults]

def getFingerprintID(self):
    """
    Returns tuples with IDs fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
    """
    return [rid for _, rid, _, _ in self.fpresults]

def getFingerprintScore(self):
    """
    Returns tuples with scores fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
    """
    return [score for score, _, _, _ in self.fpresults]

def printResults(self):
        print("Titles: %s" % self.getFingerprintTitle())
        print("Artists: %s" % self.getFingerprintArtist())
        print("IDs: %s" % self.getFingerprintID())
        print("Scores: %s" % self.getFingerprintScore())
```

when called as `./app song.mp3` outputs just some field (if one field is empty, then all the other should too and viceversa since it fetches online MP3s metadata)

```
Titles: [u'Our Day Will Come', u'Our Day Will Come', u'Our Day Will Come', u'Our Day Will Come', u'Our Day Will Come']
Artists: []
IDs: []
Scores: []
```

**with NO EXCEPTIONS in the log!**

Comment: Please post the exception traceback.

Comment: I already checked the logs and no exceptions occur.

Comment: you say it does not work. We need more info. If the code is not generating an exception then what is happening?

Comment: It's exactly why I wrote my question!

Comment: @Krishath let's phrase it another way - what do you expect it to do that it's not doing?

Comment: I think I've got it figured out.

Comment: It should print out every field! But it doesn't!

Comment: See my analysis, Krishath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to diagnose this, but it's usually more common to assign variables you're not using like this:

```
def getFingerprintArtist(self):
    """
    Returns (list of)* possible artists fetched from the MusicBrainz DB
    """
    return  [artist for _, _, _, artist in self.fpresults]
```

Can you rewrite this as a minimal reproducible example, so we can provide further guidance?

*And this is not returning a tuple, it's just returning a list of (semantically speaking) artist names!

---

**Edit- analysis**

I think what's happening here is that you're exhausting a generator.

```
self.fpresults
```

is populated once in the instantiation of the object, instead, in your `__init__` do this:

```
try:
    self.fpresults = list(acoustid.match(api_key, path))
```

It will save the information the generator produces in memory as an attribute until the `list` or the `SongFP` object is no longer referenced and then garbage collected.

Comment: GREAT! That was the problem! Could you please link me to some reference to better understand what was going on?

Comment: Here's the Python tutorial on generators: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators But the basics are that once you've iterated over a generator, it's exhausted, unless it provides a method to return to an earlier point (file/io readers could do this) but in your case, it's probably unlikely. Their upside is that they don't materialize all of their information in memory all at once. The downside is that they typically have to be recreated to be used again.

Answer (score 0):

If they're just tuples you can do like this:

```
def get_value_at_index(tuple_list, index):
    """Returns a list of the values at a given index."""
    return [tup[index] for tup in tuple_list]
```

Comment: Please check the whole code since I think my functions are just doing well but something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

with

```
[artist for score, rid, title, artist in self.fpresults]
```

you're only store artist. You need something like:

```
[(artist, score, rid, title) for artist, score, rid, title in self.fpresults]
```

Comment: That's just what the function does. Check the function name.

Comment: Ohh, I see, in that case, can you change the documentation comment for that funcrion? please?